# Can't set private static member variables with accessor

Tags: c++, static, private, member

Zombie.h has some static member variables. Read.cpp, which includes Zombie.h, knows the values that need to go in those variables. I want read.cpp to set those variables with something along the lines of

```
int Zombie::myStaticInt = 4;
```

or

```
Zombie::setStaticVar(4);
```

I've tried everything I can think of, including using a public static accessor function and even making the static variables themselves public, but I've been getting a lot of "undefined reference" or "invalid use of qualified-name" errors. By looking into those I found out how to set Zombie.h's private static member variables from Zombie.cpp, but I don't have a Zombie.cpp file, just read.cpp. Can I set them from Read.cpp instead, and if so, how?

```
// In Zombie.h
class Zombie {
public:
    static void setMax(int a_in, int b_in, int c_in) {
        a = a_in;
        b = b_in;
        c = c_in;
    }
private:
    static int a, b, c;
}

// In read.cpp
#include "Zombie.h"
...
main() {
    int Zombie::a; // SOLUTION: Put this outside the scope of main and other functions
    int Zombie::b; // SOLUTION: Put this outside the scope of main and other functions
    int Zombie::c; // SOLUTION: Put this outside the scope of main and other functions
    int first = rand() * 10 // Just an example
    int second = rand() * 10 // Just an example
    int third = rand() * 10 // Just an example
    Zombie::setMax(first, second, third);
    return 0;
}
```

This yields (Updated)
(Move first three lines of main outside of main() to solve this)

```
invalid use of qualified-name 'Zombie::a'
invalid use of qualified-name 'Zombie::b'
invalid use of qualified-name 'Zombie::c'
```

Comment: It shouldn't matter which .cpp file the lines go into, unless there's a namespace involved. Can you post some minimal code that shows the problem?

Comment: Please post your code; we can't help much without it.

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm guessing op is trying to set private variables from outside the class, based on _I found out how to set Zombie.h's private static member variables from Zombie.cpp_ , but as you said we need the code.

Comment: @computerfreaker it wouldn't matter if they're public or private, that's the thing. The compiler doesn't care what the name of the .cpp file is or whether it's related to the class name or not.

Comment: @MarkRansom Right, but if op was trying to set a private class variable from outside the class it would error out. Looks like that's not the issue, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to *define* `a,b,c` somewhere. So far you've only *declared* them to exist. In some .cpp file, at the outer scope, you need to add:

```
int Zombie::a;
int Zombie::b;
int Zombie::c;
```

**EDIT** Re your edit, you can't put them inside a method. You have to put this at the outermost scope of the .cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike non-static variables that get storage allocated in every object, static variables must have their storage outside of the class. You do this by creating definitions for the variables in a .cpp file. It doesn't matter which file they go in, although for convenience they should go with the code for the class.

```
int Zombie::a;
int Zombie::b;
int Zombie::c;
```

The linker error you're getting is telling you that these lines are missing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. After adding these, I'm back to getting "invalid use of qualified-name 'a'" (or b or c).

Comment: @Qaz it works for me: http://ideone.com/OVh8dp. You need to add more to the code to demonstrate how you're getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you haven't implemented Zombie class yet.
Your code here:

zombie.h

```
#ifndef ZBE_H
#define ZBE_H

class Zombie
{
public:
    static int myStaticInt;

    Zombie();
};
#endif
```

read.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "zombie.h"

int Zombie::myStaticInt = 1;

Zombie::Zombie()
{
}

int main()
{ 
    cout << "OOOK: " << Zombie::myStaticInt << endl;

    Zombie::myStaticInt = 100;

    cout << "OOOK: " << Zombie::myStaticInt << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In my example I used the numbers 3, 4, and 5, but in my actual code I have to use variables. If I use this code, I would need global variables to be able to do that if I'm interpreting it correctly.
What function does ok() serve?

Comment: I don't think `myStaticInt` is global, as you can see by the scope resolution operator `::`.

Comment: The variables in read.cpp whose values I am copying to Zombie are inside the scope of main(). I'd have to elevate them to global variables to use them outside main in int Zombie::myStaticInt = myVar. I'm not sure why it doesn't work from inside main(), though.

Comment: I update main() function that use Zombie::myStaticInt inside main function